# How to use ng-repeat to show a templateUrl

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat

How to use ng-repeat to show a templateUrl?
Hi guys i tryied some ways in order to show all elements of a templateUrlby using ng-repeat butunfortunatelly i didn't figure it out!Anyone who can help me with this?..This is the code.

```
   <div ng-app="myApp" ng-cloak ng-controller="Controller">

<div ><my-customer info="vaggelis"></my-customer></div>
<hr>
<div ><my-customer info="aggelos"></my-customer></div>



</div>
<script>

var app = angular.module("myApp",[])
.controller("Controller",["$scope", function($scope){
  $scope.vaggelis = {
    name : "Vaggelis",
    surname : "Kolimitras",
    age : 24
  };
  $scope.aggelos = {
    name : "Aggelos",
    surname : "Kolimitras",
    age : 21
  };
}])
.directive("myCustomer", function(){

  return{
    restrict : "E",
    scope :{
        customerInfo : "=info"
      },
    templateUrl : "my-customer.html"
  };
});

</script>
```

This is my-customer.html file

```
{{"Hi " + customerInfo.name + " " + customerInfo.surname  + " with the age of " + customerInfo.age}}
```

Comment: Use "ng-repeat" in div.
<div ng-repeat="customer in data"> <my-customer  info="customer"></my-customer>  </div>

Answer (score 0):

```
  $scope.data = {
     vaggelis = {
        name : "Vaggelis",
        surname : "Kolimitras",
        age : 24
     },
     aggelos = {
         name : "Aggelos",
         surname : "Kolimitras",
         age : 21
  }};



<div ng-app="myApp" ng-cloak ng-controller="Controller">
   <my-customer ng-repeat="cInfo in data" info="cInfo"></my-customer>
</div>
```

Hope this help to you